# Git log range revision including the range edges

Tags: git, git-log

I know that this type of questions is addressed in a lot of Q/A, I have studied them but actually I did not found a way to get the what I want.

I am looking for the git logs between two hashes including the logs of hashes used in the range.

From looking to the docs and other Q/A in SO I have found that it is achievable this way:

```
git log oldest...Newest
```

But this does not return the log of oldest is excluded.

For example in this repo https://github.com/galniv/jira-git-helper/commits/master

I want the logs between `52209d3738f80e49c724502503d6a72c1e24e6bc` as the oldest and `5456f8cecc5ef5cef5abc1f820a4f044e2153734` as the newest.

The result of `git log 52209d3738f80e49c724502503d6a72c1e24e6bc...5456f8cecc5ef5cef5abc1f820a4f044e2153734` returns only two logs instead of 3 :

```
commit 5456f8cecc5ef5cef5abc1f820a4f044e2153734
Author: Gal Niv <gal.niv@gmail.com>
Date:   Tue Mar 21 15:33:55 2017 -0400

    Update README.md

commit a4c184ecc7fb4c50705c0ac90c94752a31ce7251
Author: Gal Niv <gal.niv@gmail.com>
Date:   Tue Mar 21 11:48:30 2017 -0400

    Remove console.log, display current branch name
```

How to include the log of the oldest hash?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If there's no merge-commit involved, I'd use the ~:

`git log old-rev~1..new-rev`

That should be enough.

Comment: Even if there are merge commits involved, it should work fine.

Comment: But it fails if `old-rev` is the first commit, because there is no commit before it.

Comment: As Willem here points out, this is not a generic solution.

Comment: This is a good answer, but @McKay's is better.. as this will fail in cases where old-rev is the first commit.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
git oldest^! newest
```

The [two dot notation](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#Documentation/gitrevisions.txt-Theememtwo-dotRangeNotation) oldest..newest is just shorthand for ^oldest newest.  In other words, those commits reachable from newest but not from oldest.

"The r1^! notation includes commit r1 but excludes all of its parents." ([source](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#_other_rev_parent_shorthand_notations)).  Putting these ideas together, oldest^! newest creates a range that includes both endpoints.

Running `git rev-parse oldest^!` helped me understand how this works.

Comment: Do you mean `git log oldest^! newest` ?